# How to get only active workflow rules

Tags: query, workflow, metadata-api, tooling-api

Tooling API help to get all workflow rules, But I need only **active** workflow rules. How to get the active property information.

```
for all workflow rules (Including inactive )
/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,Name,TableEnumOrId+From+WorkflowRule
```

Comment: Try `/services/data/v34.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+ID,+TableEnumOrId,+NamespacePrefix,+Metadata+from+WorkflowRule` and see that under Metadata> workflowTimeTriggers> Active will have true/false which indicate the workflow is active or inactive

Comment: @Swetha, yes it's working with the API version 34, strange it's absent in v36! How to know all metadata API information?

Comment: I too noticed that metadata is absent from V35.I reached out to our salesforce team that owns this feature for clarification. I checked metadata information of WorkflowRule from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm

Comment: The Metadata field can only be queried if the soql query uses LIMIT 1